# Using PHP and MySQL Repeats Events

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use Upcoming events.

My table

```
ID | Name   | StartDate  | Repeats
1  | Theater| 23.09.2013 | 0
2  | Cinema | 19.09.2013 | 1
3  | Dinner | 22.09.2013 | 2
4  | Theater| 20.09.2013 | 3
5  | Cinema | 19.09.2013 | 4
```

Repeats means:

if repeat is 0 : no repeat 
if repeat is 1 : dially 
if repeat is 2 : weekly
if repeat is 3 : monthly
if repeat is 4 : yearly

I found this sql code, but i couldn't make. I want to next 2 events.

```
SELECT E.Id, E.Name, E.StartDate, E.Repeats, A.ShowDate, DATEDIFF(E.StartDate, A.ShowDate) AS diff
FROM tally AS E, (
    SELECT DATE_ADD('2012-12-09 00:00:00',INTERVAL Repeats DAY) as ShowDate
    FROM `tally`
    WHERE (DATE_ADD('2012-12-09 00:00:00',INTERVAL Repeats DAY)<='2012-12-20 00:00:00')
    ORDER BY Id ASC
) A
WHERE MOD(DATEDIFF(E.StartDate, A.ShowDate), E.Repeats)=0
AND A.ShowDate>=E.StartDate
```

Thanks for helps.

Comment: You need a "LastRun" column and check it against StartDate + Repeats

Comment: i want next 2 events.

Comment: Could it be that the where clause in your statement is looking for dates before **2012-12-20** while your data is in 2013?

Comment: Yes if I added 24.09.2012 and i choose repeat 4, then it will show

Comment: Your dates are stored using a DATE data type, right?